# Dialogflow and twillio show different results

Tags: twilio, integration, dialogflow-es, whatsapp

Hi we have created a bot making use of dialogflow for controlling natural language and twillio handles the text messaging in the form of whatsapps. We have the following code in our dialogflow fulfillment

```
    const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const {WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const {
      dialogflow,
      Image,
    } = require('actions-on-google');

    // Create an app instance
    const app = dialogflow({
      debug: true
    });

    app.intent('greeting', (conv) => {
       console.log('hi');
       //agent.add("My ID: " + conv.parameters.my_id.toString());
    });

    var name = null;
    // initialise DB connection

    var firebase = require("firebase-admin");

    var firebaseConfig = {


    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
        console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
        console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));



        function fallback(agent) {
            agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
            agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
        }

        function handleName(agent) {
            let names = agent.parameters.person;
            var temp = names;
            // agent.add(agent.requestSource);
            var name2 = agent.getContext('1_1_name');
            name = name2;

            var newData={
                name:names.name
            };

            if((temp != null && temp.name.length < 256 && temp.name.length > 2)){
                let myref = firebase.database().ref('Person');
                let mGroupId = firebase.database().ref('Person').push().getKey();   
                return true;
            } 
            else{
                agent.add('Invalid name or surname. Please try again');
                return false;
            }
        }



        function handleWelcome(agent){
            //agent.add(new Image('https://s3.amazonaws.com/botsociety.prod.us/e3d2e0b03f28399a62654d8f52bade457_welcomescreenpng.png'));
            agent.add("How can we help you?\n1: Funeral cover family option\n2: Funeral cover nominated option\n3: Add beneficiaries to existing cover\n4: Claim\n5: Contact Details");
            //agent.add(sessionId);
            return true;
        }

        function done(agent) {
          //agent.add(JSON.parse(agent.parameters).toString());
          agent.add("Lol wut");
        }

        function handleID(agent) {
          agent.add('I am a banana.');
            const id = agent.parameters.my_id;
            var tempID = id.toString();
            var valid = true;

            if (tempID.length == 13){
            }else{
              agent.add('Invalid RSA ID number. Please try again');
               return false;
            }


            //Only numerical
            for (let x = 0; x < tempID.length; x++){
                const d = tempID.charCodeAt(x);

                if (d < 48 || d > 57) 
                    valid = false;
            }

            //Valid citizenship value
            if (tempID[10] > 1)
                valid = false;

            //Odd
            var uneven = 0;
            for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x += 2){
                uneven += parseInt(tempID[x]);
            }

            //Even
            var temp = "";
            for (x = 1; x <= 11; x += 2){
                temp += tempID[x].toString();
            }

            var even = parseInt(temp) * 2;
            temp = even.toString();
            var finalEven = 0;

            for (x = 0; x < temp.length; x++){
                finalEven += parseInt(temp[x]);
            }

            //total
            var total = finalEven + uneven;
            var actualValue = 10 - (total % 10);

            //final check
            if ((actualValue.toString() !== tempID[12].toString()))
                valid = false;

            //decide what to do
            if (valid){
              let myref = firebase.database().ref('Person');
              var newData = {
                id: id
              };
            }
            else{
               agent.add('Invalid RSA ID number. Please try again');
               return false;
            }
        }

        let intentMap = new Map();
        intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
        intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);

        //Names
        intentMap.set('1_1_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('1_1_spouse_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('2_1_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('2_beneficiary_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('3_3_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('beneficiary_name_intent', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_2_c_1_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_2_c_2_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_3_c_1_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_3_c_2_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_3_c_3_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_1_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_2_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_3_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_4_name', handleName);
        intentMap.set('child_1_name_intent', handleName);

        //IDs
        intentMap.set('1_1_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('1_1_spouse_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('2_1_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('2_beneficiary_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('3_3_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('beneficiary_id_intent', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_2_c_1_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_2_c_2_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_3_c_1_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_3_c_2_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_3_c_3_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_1_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_2_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_3_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('c_4_c_4_id', handleID);
        intentMap.set('child_1_id_intent', handleID);
        intentMap.set('anything_else_no', done);
        // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
        // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
        agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

}}
```

Now the method I am most concerned with is the following.

```
 function handleID(agent) {
          agent.add('I am a banana.');
            const id = agent.parameters.my_id;
            var tempID = id.toString();
            var valid = true;

            if (tempID.length == 13){
            }else{
              agent.add('Invalid RSA ID number. Please try again');
               return false;
            }


            //Only numerical
            for (let x = 0; x < tempID.length; x++){
                const d = tempID.charCodeAt(x);

                if (d < 48 || d > 57) 
                    valid = false;
            }

            //Valid citizenship value
            if (tempID[10] > 1)
                valid = false;

            //Odd
            var uneven = 0;
            for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x += 2){
                uneven += parseInt(tempID[x]);
            }

            //Even
            var temp = "";
            for (x = 1; x <= 11; x += 2){
                temp += tempID[x].toString();
            }

            var even = parseInt(temp) * 2;
            temp = even.toString();
            var finalEven = 0;

            for (x = 0; x < temp.length; x++){
                finalEven += parseInt(temp[x]);
            }

            //total
            var total = finalEven + uneven;
            var actualValue = 10 - (total % 10);

            //final check
            if ((actualValue.toString() !== tempID[12].toString()))
                valid = false;

            //decide what to do
            if (valid){
              let myref = firebase.database().ref('Person');
              var newData = {
                id: id
              };
            }
            else{
               agent.add('Invalid RSA ID number. Please try again');
               return false;
            }
        }
```

This function is meant for validating an ID that the user provides us and works perfectly within the testing system within dialogflow test console. It is also connected to a twillio account and when we whatsapp a certain number it acts in the same way. However the validate ID function does not seem to work within twillio. It works perfectly when tested in the console but does not work well when the user uses the twillio whatsapp number.

Any suggestions as to way it does not work with the twillio integration? Thank you very much.

Edit when looking through the firebase logs I get the following error message

```
Error: No responses defined for platform: twilio
at WebhookClient.send_ (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:488:13)
at promise.then (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:306:38)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Comment: Just FYI, I might consider hiding your API credentials on here so they don’t get stolen

Comment: Thx for the heads up they were not meant to be there